# rails algorithm visitors count

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, visitor-statistic

Which is the best way to implement visitor's logic?

1. Create visitors table |ip|resource_type|resource_id|
2. Create serialize field in records (Post, Pet, Event, Ad, etc...)
3. Use nosql solutions
4. Any other idea

   - In the 1st case, we have extended the table size for every visit.
   - In the 2nd, we have a long field.
   - In the 3nd, I have trouble with mongoid at production (centOS).

Comment: Do you want to count visits? increment some counters in redis! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I'm answering, but I would not implement that myself, but rather take a look at existing solutions. For basic counting :

- [Vanity](https://github.com/assaf/vanity)
- Google Analytics

For more detailed metrics about what each user does, I would go toward [cohort](https://github.com/n8/cohort_me).

A totally other option could be using just the log and something like [lograge](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge) to log each request. It is very easy to add fields (such as the IP). You can then extract all the informations from your logs.